# Does Helm have a limit to the size of its history?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

The command `helm history` prints a list of the past revisions for a release. Is there a limit to the size of this history? i.e. a number `n` such that if there are `n + 1` revisions then the first revision is no longer available? I'm aware of the `max` flag for the `helm history` command which limits the length of the list returned, so this question could be equivalently asked as: does the `max` flag have a limit for its value?

This is in the context of wanting to do a `helm rollback` - that command requires a revision and I want to confirm that there will never be a problem with Helm forgetting old revisions.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It does have a limit, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/cmd/helm/history.go#L61) (also [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/helm/option.go#L474)) you see that it's defined as an `int32` in Golang.

Then, if you look at the [`int32`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int32) docs for the builtin-types you see that it's range is `-2147483648` through `2147483647`. In theory, you can specify `--max` on the helm command line as a positive number so `2147483647` would be your limit. (Surprisingly, I don't see where the absolute value for the int32 gets generated)

The [releaseInfo](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/8be42bae885a04b4acc242cf420911145b32ee1c/cmd/helm/history.go#L34) structure has a memory footprint, so if you have a lot of releases you will run into a limit depending on how much memory you have on your system.

Answer (score 0):

In helm 3. Default is 10 unless you specified the max history.

For example helm upgrade with command --history-max:
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

--history-max int              limit the maximum number of revisions saved per release. Use 0 for no limit (default 10)